# Add partition cannot change to D

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I want to change a path of a new volume in windows 7 to D.

I cannot chose in the disk management the letter D, I already tried to delete the D in the register; only this didn't work out as well.

I shrink the C and have the new volume of 2 TB . Also of course, I have the Recovery and OEM partition.

The D path name is not used in the Disk management. I need the letter of the path for company software to be the letter D.

[image]
[Large Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFcqY.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of Disk Management window? Please upload it to some 3rd party image hosting service (like imgur.com) and add a link to your question (use the [edit] button). We'll embed the image for you, you can't do it yet as you don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: @gronostaj http://imgur.com/g3fZWtg normal stack user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the drive letter of your CD/DVD drive. Once you do that, `D` will become available for you to map.

[image]

Comment: so terrible stupid of me

Comment: Done it myself. Glad it was something simple for you to fix!

Comment: That's why I couldn't delete it in the servers register. I was looking under the wrong rock.